# derivative of a mix function

Tags: calculus

$$\frac d {d \theta} (w\log(1+(1-\theta)P \eta )- \mu Ph \exp(-k \theta)) =0$$

How can I solve this problem for $\theta$, where I want to maximize this function w.r.t to $\theta$

Comment: Is theta a function of x otherwise the expression does not depend on x.

Comment: Could you clarify ? Just write the function for which the derivative has to be zero. Parenthese do not match.

Comment: I am sorry the the derivative is taken with respect to the theta , the x is actually theta it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $$f(\theta)=w \log (1+  (1-\theta ) P\eta)- \mu P h e^{-k \theta  }$$ you have $$f'(\theta)=\frac d {d\theta}f(\theta)=h k \mu  P e^{-k\theta }-\frac{\eta  P w}{1+  (1-\theta ) P\eta}$$ The solution for $\theta$ of $f'(\theta)=0$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$\theta=1+\frac{1}{\eta  P}-\frac{1}{k}W\left(\frac{ w}{h \mu  P}e^{k(1+\frac{1}{\eta  P})} \right)$$

The wikipedia page shows (in many examples) the series of manipulations you have to do to arrive to such a result.

Sooner or later, you will learn that any equation which write or can rewrite as $$A+Bx+C\log(D+Ex)=0$$ shows explicit solution(s) in term of Lambert function.

If you cannot use Lambert function, only numerical methods will do the job.